# The p5js library's loadFont function does not seem to work for me?

Tags: fonts, p5.js

I even copied the exact code from the reference and pasted into a new project and it just always tells me that the file path is incorrect.

I tried using the following code:

```
`function preload() {font = loadFont('MightySouly-lxggD.ttf')}`
```

to load a font I downloaded to use, but it instead gave an error saying the file path may be incorrect. The same result occurred when I used the exact code from the reference page showing how to use loadFont().

Comment: Are you running a web server to serve that file?